# Java regexp - "()" brackets

Tags: java, regex

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a>([a-zA-Z]+)</a>")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<a>Text</a>");
matcher.find()
String str = matcher.group();
```

I want to get `"Text"` to str, but I get `"<a>Text</a>"`. Why and how should I do it properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the index of the group, 1 in this case:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a>([a-zA-Z]+)</a>")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<a>Text</a>");
matcher.find()
String str = matcher.group(1);
```

[Documentation for `Matcher.group(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)

Answer (score 5):

`matcher.group()`, with no arguments, returns the entire matched substring. Use `matcher.group(1)` to retrieve just the contents of the first parenthesized capture-group:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a>([a-zA-Z]+)</a>")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<a>Text</a>");
matcher.find();
String str = matcher.group(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another overload of group() on matcher. Try:

```
matcher.group(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `group(1)`; the first group is the entire pattern.

See the [group()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) and [group(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) docs.

Answer (score 2):

`group()` returns the entire matched text. You want `group(1)`, which returns the first paren-delimited group within the match. See the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

you have to call `matcher.group` with the number of your capture group - if you omit the argument the complete match will be returned.

best regards, carsten

ps:
the best address to quickly solve these kinds of question is to look up the repective part of the [java api docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).